# Firebase Dynamic links handling error

Tags: android, android-manifest, dynamic-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

Firebase Dynamic links handling error: Onclicking Dynamic link, it is opening the launcher activity instead of activity with intent-filter (DynamicLinkHandlerActivity).

**Launcher activity:**

```
<activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"> 

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

**Dynamic link Handler:**

```
<activity android:name=".LinkHandler" > 

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="dynamic.link.code"
            android:pathPattern="/?link"
            android:scheme="https" />

    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="dynamic.link.code"
            android:pathPattern="/?link"
            android:scheme="http" />

    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use your link value's intent filter in your manifest, not the dynamic link.

For example for dynamic link : https://appcode.app.goo.gl/?link=https://example.com&...

Your resolving activity intent filter should be

`<data 
android:scheme="https"
android:host="example.com"/>`